# Why is the instantaneous magnitude of current and voltage in a phasor diagram given by the vertical components of the phasor vectors?

Tags: voltage, current, phasor

In general, if a phasor is rotating, the instantaneous voltage is given by
\$i_m\sin(\omega t)\$

where   \$i_m\$  is the amplitude of the current.

Similarly, voltage is given by \$v_m\sin(\omega t)\$ where   \$v_m\$  is the amplitude of the voltage.

However, I'm not able to think of any reason as to why we take the vertical component, why not the horizontal?

Is it just convention?

Comment: For inline math use `\$` and for its own paragraph use `$$`.

Comment: Actually, the complex form is \$ \pmb{V} = V_{0}\: e^{j\left(\omega t+\phi\right)} \$ and the *convention* is to take the real part, or \$ V_t = \mathcal{Re}\left[\pmb{V}\right]= V_{0}\: \textrm{cos}\left(\omega t+\phi\right) \$. Note the cosine and not the sine? I think your question starts with a false premise.

Comment: @jonk My book says it's sin(https://imgur.com/a/m2dQm77), so is that wrong?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, I'll try my best to use the mathJaX that EESE uses, I'm still used to the on on MSE and PSE, sorry

Comment: @fhhh If it were sine, then it follows that \$V_t = \mathcal{Im}\left[\pmb{V}\right] \$. Do you think that is what may have become the convention? But what do I know about convention? I'm just a stupid hobbyist. Please read Chas. Proteus Steinmetz's paper, *"Complex Quantities and their use in Electrical Engineering"*, from 1893. Or the more modern paper by A. E. A. Araújo & D. A. V. Tonidandel, *"Steinmetz and the Concept of Phasor: A Forgotten Story"*, 2012. Then you tell me.

Comment: @jonk sorry If I insulted you, I'm just in high school so I can hardly understand whatever you said , and when I said, is that wrong, I was referring to the book, not your answer.

Comment: @fhhh No insult taken. I'm self-educated. Just putting things, bluntly, that's all. I do ***read*** a lot. You should too. Those references are intentional -- Steinmetz is the man who literally created the convention. That goes back almost 130 years ago!!! The second reference is modern (only a decade ago) and provides a summary that is easy to read. Bottom line is that over the entire span of almost 130 years -- at least for 120 years since Steinmetz's "*Theory and Calculation of Alternating Current Phenomenta*" book in 1897 -- there is a convention. And it's not sine. Trust no one. Verify.

Comment: @fhhh Oh, and if you aren't familiar with Euler's -- GET FAMILIAR with it!!! I highly recommend ***3blue1brown*** as a youtube author of great mathematical material. Definitely look up his videos on complex numbers and Euler's. If you get crazy about things look up his work on quaternions and Euler's *gamma function*! He's really, really good. Very visual. Very beautiful! (No electronics, sadly. But his work directly applies.) I really envy you the fact you are in high school, interested in these ideas enough to ask us about them and that there is so much available to you now! Best wishes!

Comment: @fhhh If you lived near me, I'd already have been impressed by your question and would very much want to spent time with you on these topics, passing along what I feel I've learned over some decades' time. So don't get me wrong! I think you are doing very well to ask the question you did ask. Smart stuff. Just the fact that you could compose the question at your age is already impressive enough. I think you will do very well. Keep it up!

Comment: The vertical component is magnitude; the horizontal component is time.

Comment: @jonk, thank you!

Comment: @Chu, I see, thank you.

Comment: @Chu I don't think it's right to say the horizontal component is time. The horizontal component decreases over part of the cycle! You can't say you're going backwards in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's just convention.

The rotating phasor is just a useful model for understanding what's going on. If you take either component of the phasor (the vertical or the horizontal component), you get a sinusoidal signal, which is the correct answer. Both approaches are equally valid.

Here are four examples, with #2, 3, and 4 just taken from the top Google hits for "phasor":

1. Your image linked in your original question uses the vertical component.
2. [The Wikipedia animation of a phasor](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Unfasor.gif) uses the horizontal component.
3. [This tutorial](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/phasors.html) uses the vertical component.
4. [This intro from a college course](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/BackGround/phasor/phasor.html) (see the animation halfway down the page) uses the horizontal component.

So, it's a pretty even split. The advantage of the vertical component (the sine) is that it draws quite nicely into an easily-understandable diagram like the image you linked. But most engineers use the convention of the horizontal component (the cosine) since it uses the "real" component of the complex (real + imaginary) number and it's the convention that is taught in most universities.